# I need to toggle a select element in option tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Am looking to toggle a select element. I have a Select tag as follows :-

```
 <select id="orgAssign" multiple="true">
   <option selected="" value="10047">test1</option>
   <option selected="" value="10046">test2</option>
   <option value="10033">test3</option>
   <option value="10032">test4</option>
</select>
```

As seen from the html, the selected options have values, 10047 & 10046. This is native select from the browser. I want to toggle the options. That is  When the user clicks on them the first time, they are highlighted(selected) & when the user clicks on the same element the second time the element is unhighlighted(deselected).

The jquery am trying to achieve this is as follows:-

```
highlightOrg: function(event){

    var $el = $(event['target']);

    $el.toggle().css({'background-color':'#dadfff'});

}
```

The element is highlighted(selected), but when the user clicks on it the second time, it is not unhighlighted(deselected). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't that kinda defeat the purpose of using a `select` element?

Comment: It absolutely does, @JoshC :)

Comment: `$(this).attr("selected","selected")` and `$(this).removeAttr("selected")` cant do the trick?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VVXE9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to overload a select to do something counter-intuitive to the end user, why not make your own input element?

You can simply use styled `div` elements to present the data to the user, and a little JavaScript/jQuery to handle it:

```
<div id="orgAssign" class="selectGroup">
   <div class="selectItem selected" data-value="10047">Test 1</div>
   <div class="selectItem selected" data-value="10046">Test 2</div>
   <div class="selectItem" data-value="10033">Test 3</div>
   <div class="selectItem" data-value="10032">Test 4</div>
</div>
```

jQuery to toggle elements:

```
$('.selectItem').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    getValues();
});
```

jQuery to get values:

```
function getValues() {
    var values = [];
    $('#orgAssign .selected').each( function() {
           values.push($(this).data('value'));
    });

    return values;
}
```

[<kbd>JSFiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/cBn8m/)

Comment: I can use this solution too. Thanks Jeff.